# Google Appengine - How to Tail Logs in Terminal?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am looking for a similar functionality like:

`heroku logs --tail`

but for Google Appengine. Does anyone know of its existence?

Comment: yes, open the logs in console developers!

Comment: yeah. but obviously I'm looking for a CLI solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen gcloud preview app logs read?
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/logs/

Answer (score 5):

gcloud app logs tail is now in generally available!

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail

Comment: Still in beta for now, at least in the cloud shell:
$ gcloud app logs tail
ERROR: (gcloud.app.logs) Invalid choice: 'tail'.
This command is available in one or more alternate release tracks.  Try:
  `gcloud beta app logs tail` But that works great!